# Highcharts: export image show wrong color and line width if user change the color and/or line width

Tags: highcharts, colors, export, width

I created a chart, and a button to change series color to red. However, after the series color got changed to red, the export image (PNG/JPEG/PDF/SVG) still show the original color (blue) instead of the new color (red).

The way that I change a series color is as follows:

```
series.color = "#FF3030";
series.graph.attr({
    stroke: "#FF3030"
});
series.legend.colorizeItem(series, series.visible);
$.each(series.data, function (i, point) {
    point.graphic.attr({
        fill: "#FF3030"
    });
});
series.redraw();
```

I expect the exported image has the new color (red). The code is shared [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anVxk/). The same issue can happen if user change the line width programmatically. Anyone can help me to resolve these 2 issues, i.e., export the new color and width when exporting images.

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export chart, then it is created again. So as a result, dynamic elements (modified in SVG) like color are skipped. You need to use series.update() and then exported image will be correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/anVxk/2/

```
 series.update({
        color:'red'
    });
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update()

Comment: What if each point has different color by means of point.graphic.attr({ fill: color }) ?